# Finding the p.d.f. of the T distribution

Tags: integration, statistics

A question from Hogg & Tanis, 8th edition, p. 255, states:  Let $X_1 \sim N(0, 1)$ and $X_2 \sim \chi^2\left(r\right)$ be independent.  Furthermore, let $Y_1 = X_1 / \sqrt{X_2/r}$ and $Y_2 = X_2$.  What is the joint p.d.f. of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$?  What is the marginal p.d.f of $Y_1$?  Show that $Y_1$ has a $T$ distribution.

I *think* I've made some progress on the first question.  Before tonight, I'd actually never covered transformations of more than one variable.  Nevertheless, I found that $x_1 = y_1\sqrt{y_2/r}$ and $x_2 = y_2$.  If $f(x_1, x_2) = f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)$ is the joint p.d.f. of $X_1$ and $X_2$, then the joint p.d.f. of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ is $g(y_1, y_2) = f(y_1\sqrt{y_2/r}, y_2)\cdot\sqrt{y_2/r}$, with the last root being the Jacobian of the transformation.

At this point, I broke $f$ up into its constituent parts:

$$g(y_1, y_2) = f_1\left[y_1\sqrt{y_2/r}\right]f_2(y_2)\cdot\sqrt{y_2/r}$$

However, I'm having some doubts about doing so, as $f_1$ has both $y$ variables as its input; I wouldn't think that they're still independent.  If it *is* correct to break up, though, I get:

$$g(y_1, y_2) = \frac{\exp\left[-\left(y_1\sqrt{y_2/r}\right)^2/2\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\frac{y_2^{r/2-1}e^{-y_2/2}}{\Gamma(r/2)\cdot2^{r/2}}\cdot\sqrt{y_2/r}$$

I can simplify this a little bit, but apparently not in any meaningful way.  By that, I mean it sorta kinda looks like the T distribution's p.d.f. — e.g., I can get a $\sqrt{\pi r}$ in the denominator, etc. — but there are some key differences.  Furthermore, I have no idea how to integrate this thing to get the marginal p.d.f.  Could anyone offer suggestions on where to go next or, perhaps more likely, where to go back and proceed differently from?

Answer (score 1):

What you've done looks right.  I think what you're missing is that if you think of $g$ as a density of $y_2$ treating $y_1$ as a parameter then you essentially have something close to the density of a Gamma distribution.  Since you know that densities integrate to one........

Comment: Let me add that $\exp[ - (y_1 \sqrt{y_2/r})^2/2]= \exp[ -y_1^2 y_2/2r]$.

Comment: I've since seen a change of variables that makes this tractable--namely, let $u=y_2(1+y_1^2/r)$. From there, I was able to do a lot of algebraic manipulation to get it in a form that exploits the density's integrating to 1. Was this (i.e., the change of variables) what you had in mind? If so, how does one see something like that?